# where public schema is defined in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I did search, but couldn't get clear clue. There is 'public' schema in postgres. But where is the schema defined? I only see it when I create a new db. More I want to know is where it is defined and how to change it.

Thanks in advance.

Yang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `public` schema is created in the `template0` and `template1` databases by the `initdb` command when the database cluster is initialised.

When you create a new database the `template1` database is copied (cloned) to create the new database unless you specify a different template. All the contents of the template database are copied, so the new database starts out with a `public` schema.

You can customise the `template1` database - or make new databases to use as templates, specifying them with the `TEMPLATE` option to the `CREATE DATABASE` command.

See [the documentation on template databases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

If you want custom templates I'd recommend making a new DB as a template and customising it how you want. It's perfectly reasonable to `DROP` the `public` schema.

Comment: How to show the definition in template? I got it. Forget the question. :) I guess my mate sometime wrongly put his schema into the template1. So every time a new db is created, his schema is always copied. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed; It is created when you create the db.

There is nothing else special about it other than it is the default schema you get after `createdb` and is the default search_path. You are free to `DROP` it, create another one named 'public' or operate completely without one named 'public'.

Just make sure you have something useful in your [search_path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) or you might end up having to type fully-qualified names all day.

Comment: Yes. But my question where it is defined? When I create a new db, there are always several table there. I guess they are from 'public' schema. Hope my understanding is correct. So I want to check where the 'public' is defined.

Comment: Based on your edit, I believe you are talking about the [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/catalogs.html). These actually live in a schema of their own, but are magically always part of the schema-search-path.

Comment: May not far to system catalogs. I have several databases in my server. All of tables are defined in 'public' schema ('\d' can show it), But only the tables at one db are always there when a new db is created. I understand the reason is they are in 'public' schema. But why only the several tables in this db, not other tables which are also in 'public' schema. I'm checking on it.

Comment: Thanks for the basic concept about postgres. It helps.